# Facebook app - iframe, не показывается в приложении самого facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-api, facebook-graph-api

[image: Скриншот апс настроек]

Сделал iframe приложение, для фейса, если смотреть по закрепленному за ним урлом через браузеры десктопные то все ок, я его вижу и даже могу с ним взаимодействовать. А если попытаться открыть его через найтивное приложение файсбука, то пишет - страница не найдена. Логично понимаю что какие то права где то не включил, но не понимаю где :)

[image: скрин с телефона]

Comment: Откройте через safari

Comment: Через сафари работает все отлично, но причем тут это? Мне надо чтоб работало еще и в самом найтивном приложении фейса

Comment: Создайте тестовое приложение и приведите код.

Comment: вы на скрине все видите, код приложения там не нужен, там нужна только страница HTML и все которую надо показать через их iframe c POST запросом. Там нет ни какого кода вообще специального.

Comment: А другие iframe отображаются?

Comment: все работает отлично но в браузерах во всех, как только я пытаюсь выбрать, что нужно открыть через приложение facebook пишет вот такую ошибку.

Comment: С любыми другими iframe?

Comment: Если в iframe вставить любой другой домен тоже самое. https или http не имеет значение